How should I cache a REST API call with a lot of items and a relatively small limit per API call?
I want to use this API from NASA for a small project: https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY
My issue is that when I want to call this API, it only shows 20 items and I have to call it again with a different page number for another 20 items. How can I cache this result so I can use it instantly?

If the file doesn't exist, fetch from NASA API, save it, and serve
If has a JSON file, it will response it instead of call NASA API.
Max page is 1768. it is hard code but it works.
I got it from response's total_pages value.
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "total_elements": 35374,
        "total_pages": 1769,
        "number": xxxx
    }

This demo code will work simple cache.
Demo
Save as server.js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const apiKey = 'Your API Key';
const maxPages = 1768; // Set the maximum number of pages to prevent over-fetching

app.get('/v1/neo/browse', async (req, res) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10);
    if (isNaN(page)) {
        return res.status(400).send('Valid page query parameter is required');
    }
    
    if (page < 0 || page > maxPages) {
        return res.status(400).send('Page number is out of range');
    }

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'responses', `response_page_${page}.json`);
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        res.sendFile(filePath);
    } else {
        // If the file doesn't exist, fetch from NASA API, save it, and serve
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?page=${page}&size=20&api_key=${apiKey}`);
            
            // Save the response to a file
            const dir = './responses';
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
            
            res.sendFile(filePath);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching from NASA API: ' + error.message);
            res.status(500).send('Error fetching data');
        }
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

Install dependencies
npm install express axios

Run server
node server.js


Testing by Postman
The page is can change from 0 to 1768
http://localhost:3000/v1/neo/browse/?page=1000

Result

After call
response_page_1000.json created under response directory due to first time call. It call NASA API and save into json.
If call again for same page, it will not call NASA, just open 1000.json file and response like cache.

Next time call will quick response time due to cache.

